# What Are Good, Advanced Tools For Managing EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm looking to manage a system (or preferably multiple systems) of machines on EC2, and at present the only way I can see doing that in a reasonable way is to extend the [Typica](http://code.google.com/p/typica/) library and build a control panel that launches, configures, and checks in on machines for me.

I don't expect there to be any prefabricated solutions to exactly my problem out there, but I'm wondering if there are any good tools for managing EC2 instances out there?  Preferably in Java, but it'll more than likely be easier to learn a new language than to implement a seriously powerful control panel.

And yes, I know about Elasticfox - it's a wonderful tool, but not nearly powerful enough for what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition, there's [Cloud42](http://cloud42.net/), but while all of these tools, along with Amazon's new official Java API interface are quite nice, none of them (except Rightscale, which is awesome, but very incompatible with what I'm doing, sadly) have any sort of functionality remotely close to properly managing an application launch on the cloud.

I suspect that [Nimbus](http://workspace.globus.org/) and [OpenNebula](http://www.opennebula.org/) are actually tools closer to what I was asking about - proper automated system management, rather than just access for manual machine management, however I have not had a proper chance to investigate either of these.

For my purposes we developed our own in house tool using the [Typica](http://code.google.com/p/typica/) library and several other tools, that allowed us to give machines abstract names and launch, configure, and issue commands to them via their names rather than instance id's or private dns's.  Might be released open source, but that's not my decision unfortunately.  I'll update this if it is.

Answer (score 3):

I realize the question is from 2009, so I wanted to mention that since then Amazon released [CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) that allows you to orchestrate the launching and configuration of complex AWS environments. Additionally, we created [BitNami Cloud Hosting](http://bitnami.org/cloud) for managing ec2 servers, but I don't think this is what you want because is more focused on applications.

Comment: I saw a presentation on the open source project JClouds http://code.google.com/p/jclouds/ last year which was effectively exactly what I was looking for, and has turned into basically a more powerful version of the tool we built in house.  I haven't worked with AWS in two years, and haven't looked into those two tools, but they may very well also be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Rightscale's](http://www.rightscale.com) tools as well; their premium tools are for-money, but their free tools are fairly comprehensive too.

Comment: Thanks, but RightScale's services are unfortunately far to limited - they're great for doing things that are all but naturally set for the cloud, but for launching complex grid-based systems in EC2 without lots of configuration every time, they've got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Toolkit for Eclipse should prolly work for your needs. It is Java oriented.

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=250

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the new  iPhone application ( iAWSManager ) to manage your AWS resources from your iPhone .

http://www.iawsmanager.com

Comment: Thanks for the link, that could be quite useful, but is (I would imagine) identical to Elasticfox.  My question was in regards to tools for managing systems, not just machines.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed you want to do several distinct tasks:
 1) Launch and check-in on EC2 instances - seems to be the domain of the 
    AWS cloudwatch and autoscale services.  Maybe you can say how & why 
    those do not fit your needs?  You might look at Ylastic too though 
they probably won't work for the same reasons that RightScale won't - but you don't say what those reasons are...

2) You mention Nimbus and OpenNebula, but I think Eucalyptus (http://open.eucalyptus.com/) is what 
    you are after?  I found the "Grid" founded projects tended to miss 
    the mark quite badly.

3) For configuration of the machines I think you'll want to look at 
    [Chef][2] and Puppet.  You'll want to ask a separate question about 
    (resource ordering) differences between these two.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to the different cloud management softwares available in the market. They should be able to solve your problems.

- RightScale
- [Scalr](http://scalr.net) (disclaimer: I work there): it is open-source so I you can tweak it if it does not fit your needs.
- enStratus
- Kaavo

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Rundeck (Java Jetty) instance with a public IP for the web UI and add the rundeck server's public key to your EC2 nodes under whatever user account you want to execute tasks as for centralized management and orchestration.  Once you have populated your logical environments with your server lists, user accounts or LDAP/AD authentication, and assigned permissions for users you will be free to execute commands on any number of nodes simultaneously or via regex match and create repeatable jobs from them.

The Python boto SDK is also very useful for performing all things EC2 and creating automations against their APIs.